# Encryption in Dropbox-like Java application

Tags: java, gwt, encryption

I'm thinking about encryption in an application. The architecture consists of:

1. Server
2. Desktop client
3. Web client
4. mobile client

The goal is to allow user to store his data on the server, and access it from all clients, but to guarantee data privacy by encrypting data on the client.

Dropbox is an example of such an architecture, but as far as I know they don't do that - they must store plaintext data on their servers, otherwise they wouldn't be able to save on space by storing the same file only once, even if it was stored by multiple users.

How would you implement such an application? I'm thinking about using Java for desktop client; the same encryption code could theoretically be reused in GWT web client (compiled to Javascript) and in Android client. However, that's only in theory.

1. Is there an encryption library that's available on all these platforms?
2. What algorithms to use?
3. What about private keys? I can ask user for the password every time, but how do I ensure that private keys are the same for the same user in all clients?
4. I'd like to avoid multiple passwords; but if I use the same password for both data and authentication, how do I prevent server from giving data to a hacker which supplied the wrong password, or server from being able to decrypt user data because it has user's password?
5. What possible gotchas are there?

Comment: Data should only be encrypted on the server and while in transit from the server to the client. Why do you want to encrypt it on the client?

Comment: why shouldn't Dropbox use file hashing combined with filetype recognition? how do you assume that they don't use any encryption at all?

Comment: @BehrangSaeedzadeh I think they definitely have to be encrypted on client because of privacy (on transfer from client to server, when storing temp files on server, etc..)

Comment: @MarekSebera they don't have to be stored encrypted on the client. After all the files should be usable by other programs on the client. But they should only be encrypted while in transit from the server to the client or client to the server and for that https would be enough. On the server side, they can be stored encrypted so that if files get leaked due to security breach or something similar, attackers would need to decrypt them first, which they may not be able to if they don't have access to the secret keys that are used for encrypting them.

Comment: @BehrangSaeedzadeh yes, but encrypted while/before transfer, not encrypted after arriving to server. This would be security leak to server administrator !

Comment: @BehrangSaeedzadeh I'd like to encrypt data on the client to guarantee the user that nobody but him will be able to access the data, not even the administrator/programmer.

Comment: @MarekSebera I didn't say Dropbox doesn't encrypt data or isn't secure, I just noted that they (the company) have access to plaintext data. If they didn't, they wouldn't be able to serve the same file to different users.

Comment: @Domchi that's what I posted in my first comment. They can identify same file by grabbing file-type and md5sum of file (or similar). Without need to access plaintext

Comment: @MarekSebera Yes, they can identify it without access to plaintext with the hash, but to serve the same file to the several users they need plaintext.

Comment: @Domchi no, i don't agree, there can be some system of shared keys, so they won't have content in plaintext, but client will decrypt the file after receiving from server. And yes, I know this looks like nonsense, but it can make situation very unclear and complicated for intruder.

Comment: @MarekSebera OK, I'll allow it, it might be possible to do with public key cryptography, but still, Dropbox says that they can access files when needed for legal reasons (http://www.dropbox.com/help/27). But we've strayed from the original question...

Answer (score 2):

You actually need a few different pieces of cryto.

First, you want the client to encrypt the file for upload, and upon retrieving the encrypted payload back decrypt it.

Second, you want some method to transmitting the encrypted file for upload in a manner that insures that only the correct user can access his files.

The first problem requires a symmetric encryption algorithm. There are a bunch out there, but your best bet is probably AES. If you take a look at [gwt-crypto](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/) at they have a wrapper for the java bouncy castle implementation. That takes care of two of three of your platforms. I don't work with android platform, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't an AES implementation floating around. As for the key, you'll probably end up with a hash of a password. Just keep in mind the possibility of rainbow tables and take appropriate measures. The password used to encrypt the file need never go over the wire, as I understand your model all encryption and deception is done on the client. Since you mentioned system administrators as a potential attacker, you really need to look into key loggers, memory dumps and the like, but that's beyond the scope of the specific question you asked.

The second problem is a solved problem using TLS with client and server side certificates. Clients for such are available for all three platforms you are looking at. Whether you want make your users go through the hassle of installing client side certificates, though, is up to you. There are various fallback options but none are as well vetted.